# C, how to put number split over an array, into int

Tags: c, arrays, string, strtol

Lets say I have `char array[10]` and `[0] = '1'`, `[1] = '2'`, `[2] = '3'`, etc.

How would i go about creating `(int) 123` from these indexes, using C?

I wish to implement this on an arduino board which is limited to just under 2kb of SRAM. so resourcefulness & efficiency are key.

---

With thanks to Sourav Ghosh, i solved this with a custom function to suit:

```
long makeInt(char one, char two, char three, char four){
  char tmp[5];
  tmp[0] = one;
  tmp[1] = two;
  tmp[2] = three;
  tmp[3] = four;

  char *ptr;
  long ret;
  ret = strtol(tmp, &ptr, 10);

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Are your arrays always containing valid values ?

Comment: yes, there is error handling prior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need to know is `strtol()`. Read details [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

Just to quote the essential part

> `long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);`
>
> The `strtol()` function converts the initial part of the string in `nptr` to a `long int`eger value according to the given `base`, which must be between `2` and `36` inclusive, or be the special value `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = ((array[0] << 24) & 0xff000000) |
                ((array[1] << 16) & 0x00ff0000) |
                ((array[2] << 8) & 0x0000ff00) |
                ((array[3] << 0) & 0x000000ff);
```

This should work

Comment: Works only, if there are hex numbers in this array. OP has decimal digits as ASCII codes however

Comment: Also fails if there are 5 digits

Comment: An integer is of 4 bytes. arrays 4 indexes should be involved in this

Answer (score 2):

if you have no library with `strtol()`or `atoi()` available use this:

```
int result = 0;
for(char* p = array; *p; )
{    
    result += *p++ - '0';
    if(*p) result *= 10; // more digits to come
}
```